# The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000

Tags: xamarin, mono, nuget, xamarin-studio, nuget-package-restore

At Xamarin-Studio, when I try to restore nuget packages, I get errors:

```
Restoring NuGet package modernhttpclient.2.4.2.
Restoring NuGet package Xamarin.Build.Download.0.2.1.
Restoring NuGet package Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.23.3.0.
Restoring NuGet package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.23.3.0.
Restoring NuGet package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.23.3.0.
Restoring NuGet package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.29.0.0.1.
Restoring NuGet package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.29.0.0.1.
Restoring NuGet package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps.29.0.0.1.
Restoring NuGet package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location.29.0.0.1.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.build.download/0.2.1/xamarin.build.download.0.2.1.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.maps/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.maps.29.0.0.1.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.location/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.location.29.0.0.1.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.basement/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.basement.29.0.0.1.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/modernhttpclient/2.4.2/modernhttpclient.2.4.2.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.animated.vector.drawable/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.animated.vector.drawable.23.3.0.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.v7.cardview/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.v7.cardview.23.3.0.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.v7.mediarouter/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.v7.mediarouter.23.3.0.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.base/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.base.29.0.0.1.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.build.download/0.2.1/xamarin.build.download.0.2.1.nupkg 446ms
Acquiring lock for the installation of Xamarin.Build.Download 0.2.1
Acquired lock for the installation of Xamarin.Build.Download 0.2.1
Installing Xamarin.Build.Download 0.2.1.
Error downloading 'Xamarin.Build.Download.0.2.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.build.download/0.2.1/xamarin.build.download.0.2.1.nupkg'.
The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset
Unable to find version '0.2.1' of package 'Xamarin.Build.Download'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.Build.Download.0.2.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.build.download/0.2.1/xamarin.build.download.0.2.1.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project TK.CustomMap.Sample.iOS: Unable to find version '0.2.1' of package 'Xamarin.Build.Download'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.Build.Download.0.2.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.build.download/0.2.1/xamarin.build.download.0.2.1.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.location/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.location.29.0.0.1.nupkg 735ms
Acquiring lock for the installation of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location 29.0.0.1
Acquired lock for the installation of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location 29.0.0.1
Installing Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location 29.0.0.1.
Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.location/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.location.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset
Unable to find version '29.0.0.1' of package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.location/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.location.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project TK.CustomMap.Android: Unable to find version '29.0.0.1' of package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.location/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.location.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.basement/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.basement.29.0.0.1.nupkg 978ms
Acquiring lock for the installation of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 29.0.0.1
Acquired lock for the installation of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 29.0.0.1
Installing Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 29.0.0.1.
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.maps/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.maps.29.0.0.1.nupkg 1036ms
Acquiring lock for the installation of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 29.0.0.1
Acquired lock for the installation of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 29.0.0.1
Installing Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 29.0.0.1.
Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.maps/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.maps.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset
Unable to find version '29.0.0.1' of package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.maps/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.maps.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project TK.CustomMap.Sample.Droid: Unable to find version '29.0.0.1' of package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.maps/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.maps.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project TK.CustomMap.Android: Unable to find version '29.0.0.1' of package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.maps/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.maps.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project CalloutSample.Droid: Unable to find version '29.0.0.1' of package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.maps/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.maps.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.basement/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.basement.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset
Unable to find version '29.0.0.1' of package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.basement/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.basement.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project TK.CustomMap.Sample.Droid: Unable to find version '29.0.0.1' of package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.basement/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.basement.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project TK.CustomMap.Android: Unable to find version '29.0.0.1' of package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.basement/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.basement.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project CalloutSample.Droid: Unable to find version '29.0.0.1' of package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.basement/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.basement.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/modernhttpclient/2.4.2/modernhttpclient.2.4.2.nupkg 1230ms
Acquiring lock for the installation of modernhttpclient 2.4.2
Acquired lock for the installation of modernhttpclient 2.4.2
Installing modernhttpclient 2.4.2.
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.animated.vector.drawable/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.animated.vector.drawable.23.3.0.nupkg 1239ms
Acquiring lock for the installation of Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable 23.3.0
Acquired lock for the installation of Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable 23.3.0
Installing Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable 23.3.0.
Error downloading 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.23.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.animated.vector.drawable/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.animated.vector.drawable.23.3.0.nupkg'.
The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset
Unable to find version '23.3.0' of package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.23.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.animated.vector.drawable/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.animated.vector.drawable.23.3.0.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project TK.CustomMap.Sample.Droid: Unable to find version '23.3.0' of package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.23.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.animated.vector.drawable/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.animated.vector.drawable.23.3.0.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project TK.CustomMap.Android: Unable to find version '23.3.0' of package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.23.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.animated.vector.drawable/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.animated.vector.drawable.23.3.0.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project CalloutSample.Droid: Unable to find version '23.3.0' of package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.23.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.animated.vector.drawable/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.animated.vector.drawable.23.3.0.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.v7.cardview/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.v7.cardview.23.3.0.nupkg 1713ms
Acquiring lock for the installation of Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 23.3.0
Acquired lock for the installation of Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 23.3.0
Installing Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 23.3.0.
Error downloading 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.23.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.v7.cardview/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.v7.cardview.23.3.0.nupkg'.
The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset
Unable to find version '23.3.0' of package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.23.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.v7.cardview/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.v7.cardview.23.3.0.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project TK.CustomMap.Sample.Droid: Unable to find version '23.3.0' of package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.23.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.v7.cardview/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.v7.cardview.23.3.0.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project TK.CustomMap.Android: Unable to find version '23.3.0' of package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.23.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.v7.cardview/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.v7.cardview.23.3.0.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project CalloutSample.Droid: Unable to find version '23.3.0' of package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.23.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.v7.cardview/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.v7.cardview.23.3.0.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Error downloading 'modernhttpclient.2.4.2' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/modernhttpclient/2.4.2/modernhttpclient.2.4.2.nupkg'.
The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset
Unable to find version '2.4.2' of package 'modernhttpclient'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'modernhttpclient.2.4.2' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/modernhttpclient/2.4.2/modernhttpclient.2.4.2.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project TK.CustomMap: Unable to find version '2.4.2' of package 'modernhttpclient'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'modernhttpclient.2.4.2' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/modernhttpclient/2.4.2/modernhttpclient.2.4.2.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.base/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.base.29.0.0.1.nupkg 2251ms
Acquiring lock for the installation of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 29.0.0.1
Acquired lock for the installation of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 29.0.0.1
Installing Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 29.0.0.1.
Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.base/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.base.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset
Unable to find version '29.0.0.1' of package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.base/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.base.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project TK.CustomMap.Sample.Droid: Unable to find version '29.0.0.1' of package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.base/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.base.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project TK.CustomMap.Android: Unable to find version '29.0.0.1' of package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.base/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.base.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project CalloutSample.Droid: Unable to find version '29.0.0.1' of package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.29.0.0.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.googleplayservices.base/29.0.0.1/xamarin.googleplayservices.base.29.0.0.1.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.v7.mediarouter/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.v7.mediarouter.23.3.0.nupkg 2281ms
Acquiring lock for the installation of Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 23.3.0
Acquired lock for the installation of Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 23.3.0
Installing Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 23.3.0.
Error downloading 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.23.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.v7.mediarouter/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.v7.mediarouter.23.3.0.nupkg'.
The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset
Unable to find version '23.3.0' of package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.23.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.v7.mediarouter/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.v7.mediarouter.23.3.0.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project TK.CustomMap.Sample.Droid: Unable to find version '23.3.0' of package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.23.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.v7.mediarouter/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.v7.mediarouter.23.3.0.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project TK.CustomMap.Android: Unable to find version '23.3.0' of package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.23.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.v7.mediarouter/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.v7.mediarouter.23.3.0.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed for project CalloutSample.Droid: Unable to find version '23.3.0' of package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Error downloading 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.23.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.android.support.v7.mediarouter/23.3.0/xamarin.android.support.v7.mediarouter.23.3.0.nupkg'.
  The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
  Parameter name: offset

Package restore failed.
```

It seems that all the errors around this one:

```
The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset
```

Any one can help?

**edit**

```
mono version is:

$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.4.0 (mono-4.4.0-branch-c7-baseline/5995f74 Thu Jun  2 15:13:10 EDT 2016)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           normal
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notification:  kqueue
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          yes(3.6.0svn-mono-master/a173357)
    GC:            sgen
```

Comment: Looks like NuGet is rejecting the download request to me. What is the time and date of your local machine?

Comment: time and date of my local machine is 25/6/2016, 3:21PM, GMT +3

Comment: Mh, stange that looks good actually. This guy here seems to have a similar issue. Maybe this helps: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1984

Comment: I've got an advice, to downgrade NuGet to v2, but how would I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [bug in Mono](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37970) which affects NuGet 3.

There are two workarounds:

1. Use NuGet 2 which can be downloaded from [NuGet.org](http://dist.nuget.org/index.html). It also ships with Mono 4.4 and earlier versions.
2. Change your machine's timezone so it is using GMT+0 or a negative offset. The Mono bug occurs if you timezone has a positive offset.

Comment: I tried workaround 2 above, but it didn't work, (I just updated the timezone of my mac to USA which is GMT minus 5) , As for point 1, all downloads at the link you provided are for windows, but I am on Mac, where is the right link?

Comment: The workaround works for me on the Mac. Yes, NuGet v2 from that link will work on Mac. If you have not upgraded your local copy of nuget shipped with Mono you can also just use that.

Comment: Second workaround worked for me, but only restarting Xamarin Studio

Comment: @xleon tried every thing, but didn't restart Xamarin Studio, wasted a day or so.. thank you for your valuable hint